# Byte array in objective c with ascii encoding

Tags: c#, objective-c, encoding, utf-8, sha

I am trying to get a byte array from an NSString in objective c using ascii encoding. I need to this array to calculate the SHA256 hash of that string and then compare the result to the SHA256 encoding generated in Windows.

```
    NSString *myString = @"123456¥";
const char *string = (const unsigned char *) [myString cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncodin];
```

this always gives  `nil` since it contains the `¥` character.

the problem is I cannot use UTF8Encoding since the hash generated by windows uses ASCII encoding like so:

```
string text ="123456¥";
byte[] arrSHA = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);
```

although using UTF8 Encoding in objective c does work, I cannot use it as it will give a different byte array than the one generated in .Net which will result a completely different SHA for that string.

Any suggestions on how to make this work?

UPDATE:

reading the documentation about [ASCII encoding in .Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.ascii%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it seems that it convert every non ASCII character to `?`. Can I detect these characters in objective c and manually replace them with `?`

Regards

Comment: Your string is not ASCII, find out exactly the encoding used in Windows. Perhaps it is UTF16. Also try `NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding`, it handles the full 256 characters.

Comment: I know it's not ASCII, that's why it's giving me pain. Yet using ASCII encoding in windows to convert it to bytes works so I was wondering if someone know if somehow .net defaults to a different encoding if the string is not ASCII

Comment: So, the problem is that Windows is doing an ASCII conversion on a non-ASCII string? Fix the Windows side to use an encoding that can **correctly** handle the non-ASCII string. On Windows print out the data after the conversion to figure out what Windows is actually doing. Post that in your question.

Comment: Problem is I cannot fix the Windows side, the damage has been done and all hashes are saved on the server with ASCII encoding.

Comment: As for `allowLossyConversion` sadly it does not work, it converts the UTF8 char to the nearest ASCII char. For example, ¥ is converted to Y. If you read my update, I think I need to convert any UTF8 char in the string to a `?`

Comment: Will try it but I don't think it will solve the problem since the byte array will have the UTF8 values of the special characters

Comment: Find what the "System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes" conversion does and then write an method that does the same thing. That should really not be that hard.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution would be if the server used UTF-8 instead of ASCII encoding.
If that is not an option, you can use the following code for the conversion,
where all non-ASCII characters are substituted by a question mark
(error-checking omitted for brevity):

```
NSString *myString = @"ä123€456¥";

CFIndex asciiLength;
// Determine length of converted data:
CFStringGetBytes((__bridge CFStringRef)(myString), CFRangeMake(0, [myString length]),
                 kCFStringEncodingASCII, '?', false, NULL, 0, &asciiLength);
// Allocate buffer:
uint8_t *asciiBuffer = malloc(asciiLength);
// Do the conversion:
CFStringGetBytes((__bridge CFStringRef)(myString), CFRangeMake(0, [myString length]),
                 kCFStringEncodingASCII, '?', false, asciiBuffer, asciiLength, NULL);

// Check the result:
printf("%.*s\n", (int)asciiLength, asciiBuffer);
// Output: ?123?456?
```

There is (as far as I know) no equivalent `NSString` method, therefore you have
to use the "toll-free bridge" from `NSString` to `CFStringRef` and a Core Foundation
function.

Comment: it did not work for me and for some reason `asciiBuffer` had only one byte in it after calling the last `CFStringGetBytes` no matter what string I put, its always the same. `asciiLength` had the correct string length BTW

Comment: @RedSerpent: That is strange. I have tested the code with your input `@"123456¥"` and with other strings, and it always produced the expected result.

Comment: somehow it doesn't work for me, and yes printing the result will only give the first character.

Comment: What is your input string? What is the value of `asciiLength`? What are the return values of `CFStringGetBytes()`?

Comment: My input string is "123456¥"' the value of asciiLength = 7 and the output is just "1"

Comment: Can you show the output of `NSLog(@"%@", [myString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16BigEndianStringEncoding])` ?

Comment: `<00310032 00330034 00350036 00a5>` this is the result you requested.

Comment: @RedSerpent: OK, that is exactly the string that I tested and it worked without any problems. Very strange. Perhaps print the values of asciiBuffer[0] .. asciiBuffer[6].

Comment: Well frankly I feel I'm done with all this. I just did the conversion manually, looping on the string one character at a time and testing if the character is ASCII compatible, if not then replace that character with a `?` and its working fine.